# Ruby on Rails user list columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I was wondering how I could go about creating a list of users four columns wide?

Right now each user is just printed on a single row with a division.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you referring to the `auto-generated` scaffolds from a script/generate or rails g scaffold ?

Comment: Yes, I used a scaffold to generate the users.

Comment: What I am trying to do is use a loop to print out all the users, but I want the 4 users across. Not each on a single row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you are looking for a Rails solution and not an CSS one? Think you can do this both in CSS and Rails.

Do you want something like this (see [here for more examples](http://apidock.com/rails/Array/in_groups_of))?

```
 @users.in_groups_of(4) {|user| user.name}
 ["Tony", "John", "Frank", "Bill"]
 ["Dave", nil, nil]
```

Comment: in_groups_of(4) doesn't seem to work. I'll take a CSS solution if you have one?